# Custom compile Apache Server from source code

Tags: linux, apache, tcp, compilation

I want to build a TCP server that will support long socket connection, so for core of server i want to use Apache's core server module, is it possible to compile Apache's source code as per my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the Adobe Portable Runtime Project
https://apr.apache.org/

It handles a lot of network communications details.